# Removing duplicate commits from a public branch

Tags: git

I've duplicated commits and pushed my local branch, with duplicated commits to a public branch, and want to remove duplicated commits from the public branch.  How would I go about doing this?

I've tried cherry picking onto a new branch and then pushing that up, but I haven't been able to find all my files on the commits, and also tried to rebase before the branching point and pushing that up with git push --force-with-lease, but my remote declines it, because it would overwrite history.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate commits"?  Do you mean that the commit message is the same?

Comment: The commits have the same content, but different SHAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do it:

> git revert SHA

Comment: Thank you! reverted the commit where i pulled in changes from another branch.